# Opening Files with Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a program with tkinter that will display data from text files into the Text widget.  However, when I try to run the program , I receive ' NameError: name 'text_identity' is not defined '. Could anyone explain why this error appears, as well as how it can be fixed?

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import font
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

    class Manager:

        def __init__(self, root):
        #The frame for the GUI itself
            mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, relief=SUNKEN, padding="3 10 12 12")
            mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=10, sticky="NW")

            button_load= ttk.Button(mainframe,    text="Load",command=self.OpenFile)
            button_load.grid(row=35, column=17, sticky = "NE", padx=5, pady=10)

            text_identity = Text(mainframe, width = 15, height = 2)
            text_identity.grid(column=8, row=5, sticky=(N,W))

        def OpenFile(self):
            File1= askopenfilename()
            File2= open(File1,'r')
            text_identity.insert("1.0",File2.read())
            File2.close()

    def main():
        root = Tk()
        Manager(root)
        root.title("Data Management")
        root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == main():
        main()
```